# How to find RANSAC of X, Y, and Z in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a CSV with an X, a Y, and a Z column to give a 3D point. In the file, there is about 4000 data points. I’ve found stuff online for how to do a Random Sample Consensus (RANSAC) fit with 2D but nothing 3D and I am completely lost for finding a “best fit line” for all the graphed data points

Comment: By "best fit line", do you mean best fit *(hyper)plane*?

Comment: The [input data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html#bvhr3vi-data) for `ransac` is specified as a `mxn` matrix, not necessarily 2d.

Answer (score 0):

in Matlab, `ransac` appears to be part of the Computer Vision toolbox.  The [function help page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ransac.html#bvhr3vi-data) provides the following description of the input data:

"Data to be modeled, specified as an m-by-n matrix. Each row corresponds to a data point in the set to be modeled. For example, to model a set of 2-D points, specify the point data as an m-by-2 matrix"

this seems to indicate that you would just provide your 3D data as a m-by-3 array.  such as:

```
DATA = [ 0 0 0; 0 0 1; 1 2 3];
```

etc.

If the CSV data is nothing more than a 3 column by ~4000 row array with no other text or data, you should simply be able to read in the data as:

```
>> DATA = dlmread('data.txt')
DATA =
     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     1     2     3
```

followed by something like:

```
[model, inpoints] = ransac (DATA, ...model options...)
```

The various model parameters are described in the Matlab help page, with an example for a 2d data set comparing Least Squares fit and RANSAC using an "M-estimator SAmple and Consensus" (MSAC) model. They should be able to be extended from 2D to 3D if a distance formula is the primary evaluation for error & inclusion.

I noticed that you also tagged this question for Octave.  At this time Octave does not appear to have a compatible function to `ransac` implemented.  If you do desire to run the code in Octave, a quick search reveals a few implementations that indicate Octave compatibility, specifically:

- [The RANSAC toolbox](https://github.com/RANSAC/RANSAC-Toolbox)
- [RANSAC for Dummies](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~turkel/imagepapers/RANSAC4Dummies.pdf)
- [MATLAB and Octave Functions for Computer Vision and Image Processing](https://www.peterkovesi.com/matlabfns/)

Note that those implementations may differ, including the method or ability to handle 3D data.